# Unix/Linux process scheduler logs

Tags: logs, scheduling

Where can I actually see what decisions did a process scheduler make over a time period? Are there scheduling specific logs maintained by Unix/Linux systems I could take a look or should I be looking for specific lines in general logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that there does not exist such a log for the simple reason that there are so many processes scheduled every second that you'll be blown away by the amount of logging lines.